# Passing list values into a subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I want to use subprocess in python to pass multiple strings from a list into a subprocess so I can execute commands on a unix server.

I have four files S3_R1, S3_R2, S4_R1, S4_R2 and created a file with partial names.

**I am stuck trying to pass the list of strings into subprocess.run()**

I've attempted this with no success and generate an error.

```
import subprocess
partial_name_files = ['S3_R', 'S4_R']

for file in partial_name_files:
    print(subprocess.run(["commands", "-arg1 -arg2 {0}1.gz {0}2.gz"].format(file)))
```

> error message - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'format'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run `format`, a `str` method, on a `list` object (like the exception mentions).

To fix this, change the position of your `format` call:

```
print(subprocess.run(["commands", "-arg1 -arg2 {0}1.gz {0}2.gz".format(file)]))
```

Comment: sorry, I typed that in wrong and have the format position the way you've written it out. I'll update the question.

Comment: Your code in the question is still different from mine.